# for loop resizing my arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I've been banging my head on this one for a while now. My for loop below will either return `0123` if I `//` the second loop. 
But it will print out `0123` array 8 times if I don't.
 I want both loops but I can't figure out how to make them work together. I want `0123` from the first loop and the

```
[0]
[-1]
[-1]
[1]
[2]
[-1]
[-1]
[2]
```

from the second So I can compare the two. Can some one help? Can I use something else besides a for loop?

```
import java.util.*;
      public class test {
           public static List<List<Integer>> work;
           public static void main (String[] args) {
           List<String> dan = Arrays.asList  ("Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Violet", "Orange", "Blue");
           List<String> Jan =Arrays.asList("Red","Green","Blue","Blue");
           for (int i =0; i < dan.size(); i++){
         //for (int y =0; y < Jan.size(); y++){
           List<Integer> work = Arrays.asList((Jan).indexOf(dan.get(i)));
           System.out.println(work); 
                        }
                      }
                     }
                    //}
```

Comment: Don't put one loop inside the other one.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  But if you want to go through one array, then go through the other array, you want two loops **that are not nested inside one another**.  That is, `for (...) { code for first loop } for (...) { code for second loop }`.  Don't put one `for` inside the `{ }` of the other `for`.

Comment: Write clear requirement as your question is not clear

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this guys.

Comment: How would you write this with out nesting the loops?

Answer (score 0):

Your code was very far off of what it needed in terms of structure to accomplish what you wanted. Here is a quick and dirty fix that should get you close. I would recommend a lot more practice with for loops.

import java.util.*;
public class Test 
{

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    List<String> dan = Arrays.asList  ("Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Violet", "Orange", "Blue");
    List<String> Jan =Arrays.asList("Red","Green","Blue","Blue");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for (int i =0; i < Jan.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(i); 
    }
    System.out.println(""); line break between the output.



    List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i =0; i < dan.size(); i++)
    {
        found = false;
        for (int y =0; y < Jan.size(); y++)
        {
            if( dan.get(i) == Jan.get(y) )
            {   
                temp.add(y);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(found == false)
        {
            temp.add(-1);
        }
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < temp.size(); j++)
    {
        System.out.println(temp.get(j));
    }

}
```

}

Comment: hey thanks for taking me some what seriously lol. I'll pour over your code later today. Thanks alot

Comment: Question what's a efficient way of using the index info from temp.get(j)) to place the colors in Jan.list in those potions?